# How to teach that $10000x^2$ c$^2$m$^2$ is wrong?

Tags: units

How do you teach to teenagers or kids that if we have a square with side length $x$ m (that is, $100x$ cm), then its area is $x^2$ m$^2,$ but not $10000x^2$ c$^2$m$^2$ ?

Comment: Do you presume these students understand what the unit "cm" means -- that it is not "c" times "m"?

Comment: Are you currently experiencing this, or is it just a curiosity? I ask because in my experience, it is far more likely that a student would say the answer is either $10000 x \text{cm}$ or possibly $10000 x^2 \text{cm}$ before they would consider squaring each letter in a unit.

Comment: I mean, $\textrm{c}^2\textrm{m}^2$'s being a non-standard notation for $(\textrm{cm})^2$? Certainly, but to play devil's advocate (or to someone not knowing otherwise) formally interpreting $\textrm{c}$ as an operator that multiplies by $1/100$ -- like the percent symbol is sometimes presented -- makes it all make perfect sense. So, especially if the learner simply has their own conception of what they had meant, yet to be articulated, I would say such an answer is less wrong than reflective of missing familiarity or acculturation.

Comment: That's the reason you usually use units like meter and not centimeter. The right way would be to expand the prefix centi to 1/100 to see what you're doing and that meter is the unit you're talking about.

Comment: I like the answer below, but if I were having this issue with my students and wanted them to keep it simple I'd force them to read it out loud.  They say $(cm)^2$ so they should write it.  Otherwise I expect them to say centi-squared  meters-squared.  It stresses the difference outlined in ryang's answer without forcing them to calculate it.

Comment: This is pitched at the wrong level, but might be helpful for someone who (1) knows more mathematics and (b) is teaching people who know less.  https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But $x^2$ m$^2$ and $10000x^2$ c$^2$m$^2$ are arguably **both correct**.

The prefix ‘centi’ means a hundredth, and the convention \begin{align}\text{cm}^2:={}&(\text{cm})^2\\={}&(10^{-2}\text{ m})^2\\={}&10^{-4}\text{ m}^2\end{align} does not preclude the curious-looking first intermediate step in the presentation \begin{align}(100x\text{ cm})^2&{}\color{red}{=100^2x^2\text{ c}^2\text m^2}\\&=100^2(0.01)^2 x^2\text{ m}^2\\&=x^2\text{ m}^2,\end{align} which is just as sound and solid as the presentation
\begin{align}
2000\text{ cm$^2$/h}&=2000\left(\frac1{100}\text{ m}\right)^2\left(60^2\text{ s}\right)^{-1}\\
&=5.56\times10^{-5}\text{ m$^2$/s}.
\end{align} In all the above, ‘centi’ and ‘$\%$’ perform the function of dividing by $100:$ the former as a prefix operator, whilst the latter as a [postfix operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4399862/21813).

P.S. Likewise for [deci, milli, micro, nano, kilo, giga, etc.](https://www.nist.gov/pml/owm/metric-si-prefixes).

P.P.S. While obtaining the above link, I learnt that *deca* is the only such prefix whose symbol ‘da’ has two characters. Since *milli* versus *mega* is ‘m’ versus ‘M’, it's a shame that *deci* versus *deca* couldn't just be ‘d’ vesus ‘D’.

Comment: xy^2 ≠ (xy)^2, so I don't follow....Now if you said cm^2 is one hundredth of a square meter...well, I guess it would still be in violation of SI standards. Which probably should be noted. I did learn here that a centipede is so-called because it's a hundredth of a foot long. Right? :)

Comment: In particular c^2m^2 as implicitly equivalent to (cm)^2" (which steps you omitted in expanding (100x cm)^2). "c^2m^2" is not allowed in the SI/ISO standards. (Honestly, I thought your answer was tongue-in-cheek. So was my comment, at least in parts.)

Comment: $xy^2=(xy)^2$ was tongue-in-cheek, and came from substituting $x$ and $y$ into $\rm cm^2 := (cm)^2$. But the serious point is about $\rm c^2m^2$.

Comment: @Raciquel I'm struggling to decipher which sentence/point you are disagreeing with (or misunderstanding), or if you are merely making humorous remarks. To be clear: 1. while the OP's student is correct to *understand* that $(\text {cm})^2=\text c^2\text m^2,$ notice that the RHS is an intermediate step rather than the final answer, and certainly not in 'publication format'. $\quad$ 2. the *convention* that I specified around the definition symbol `:=` is agreed on by everyone (including the ISO, the OP, myself, and presumably you), under the given that 'centi' isn't an atomic physical unit.

Comment: $\rm (cm)^2 = c^2m^2$ is incorrect per international standards. That is what I'm disagreeing with. Mathematician can make up a system that is consistent if they want to, but as units are more important in science and engineering, they shouldn't do it in this case.  I find it fun to do so, privately, or with others who also enjoy this sort of play.  If taken seriously, it is just wrong per conventional definitions. (The side issue of whether one is permitted to separate c from m in $\rm(cm)^2$ but not in $\rm cm^2$ is not that important.)

Comment: @Raciquel Ah okay, fair enough; I just edited the answer to leave no doubt that I'm not advocating leaving the final answer as $74\text c^2\text m^2,$ haha.  $\quad $That step isn't just frivolous fun though; a student who writes that hasn't done anything invalid (and probably has a good understanding), because *centi*, *kilo*, etc. *are*, by design, genuine prefix operators.

Comment: @ryang I'm skeptical that a student who writes $(x\ \text{cm})^2 = x^2\ \text{c}^2\text{m}^2$ has a good understanding. They could simply be applying the formal rule that $(ab)^2=a^2b^2\!$.

Comment: @ryang I deleted that part when I thought about it some more but before I saw your new comment. I do still think that saying $\text{c}^2\text{m}^2$ is *valid* is a bit hairy. If we do treat $\text{c}$ as a prefix operator, it's still not generally permissible to apply operators to other operators. The answer you linked to in your post for example says that $\frac{7}{\%}$ is meaningless, and I would say the same for $7^2\%^2\!$.

Comment: @JustinHancock 1. Perhaps; if said student writes $(x\ \text{cm})^2 = x^2\ \text{c}^2\text{m}^2$ in an intermediate step, but wouldn't write $(x\ \text{metres})^2 = x^2m^2e^2t^2r^2e^2s^2$ (this is quite likely the case), then I think they are fine! $\quad$ 2. logical negation: $\lnot\lnot\forall x\,Px$

Comment: @ryang We can parse $\neg\neg(\forall x Px)$ as $\neg(\neg(\forall x Px))$. The first negation operates on the statement $\neg(\forall x Px)$, not directly on the second negation. In $(\text{cm})^2\!$, we are squaring the unit $\text{cm}$, not squaring the operator $\text{c}$ and unit $\text{m}$ separately.

Comment: @ryang Students' abilities are highly context dependent. Understanding that "centimeter" is a unit when they see $(x\ \text{centimeters})^2$ and writing down $x^2\ \text{square centimeters}$ does not automatically mean that they have the same understanding of $(x\ \text{cm})^2\!$. Connecting these two contexts in students' minds is one of the purposes of exercises like $(100x\ \text{cm})^2 =\ ?\ \text{m}^2\!$. Allowing $\text{c}^2\text{m}^2$ detracts from this, because we don't say "centi squared meters squared."

Comment: @Justin You opined that $(49\%)\%$ is impermissible in the same way as [whatever illegality you think the student was committing], so I offered the negation example, which is identical to the percentage example that you gave! $\quad$ You're fixating on your impression that said student is treating x, c, m as similar algebraic objects; it doesn't have to be this way (not that this shorthand framing is necessarily wrong): said student possibly understands that centi stands for $10^{-2},$ so casually treats it as such; they are after all writing mathematics (an informal language), not Java code.

Comment: @JustinHancock I've never seen anyone write $59\text{ c}^2\text m^2,$ but if I do and there is neither evidence of misunderstanding nor sign that the student thinks that it is an acceptable final answer, then I'm good; but yes I understand that your mileage varies.

Comment: @ryang I'm okay with $(49\%)\%$, although it's a bit clunky.  It's not the same as $49\%^2\!$, which if we interpret it as you say, seems equivalent to $49(\%)^2$. Do you think that $49(\%)$ is permissible? If we treat it as a **postfix operator**, then I don't think it is. To me, the symbols $\%$ and $\text{c}$ do not signify the number $10^{-2}\!$. They are operator symbols. $\%$ operates on numbers, and $\text{c}$ operates on simple units (units without prefixes.) Because $(\cdot)^2$ operates on numbers or quantities and not operators, $\%^2$ and $\text{c}^2$ are category mistakes.

Comment: @ryang I forgot—$(\cdot)^2$ can also operate on units, like $\text{m}^2$ or $\text{cm}^2\!$. Basically on any objects for which there is a notion of multiplication.

Comment: @JustinHancock I deliberately wrote "$(49\%)\%$" instead of your "$49\%^2$" for a reason; and my response to the rest of your new comments is in the chunk, "You're fixating on...". $\quad$ My previous comment was intended to be my closing statement; shall we just leave it at that? -)

Comment: So how do you deal with square miles?  For example $640~\text{acres} = 1~\text{mi}^2$---$1~\text{m}^2\text{i}^2$ is complete nonsense here.

Comment: @XanderHenderson This issue (is outside the OP's scope but) was already brought up in [comment #9](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/26283/how-to-teach-that-10000x2-c2m2-is-wrong/26284?noredirect=1#comment69438_26284). $\quad$ On a tangential note, does the median teenager (or the general public) really not discern that `100 Mbps`, `1 Gbps`, `7 MB`, `4 kB` (sometimes: `4 KB`) are of the form 'Number-Multiplier-BaseUnit'? (To be clear, I'm *not* expecting them to know conversions like 'micro = 1000 x nano' or even 'centi = 10 x milli'

Comment: nor that kilo equals either 1000 or 1024 depending on the industry.) Do language teachers sleeplessly fret that their students are unable to use natural language, since even simple sentences can require common sense and context to correctly understand/disambiguate?

Comment: I had not seen that comment, but you haven't really satisfactorily addressed my point.  You are introducing a very uncommon convention ($1~\text{cm} = 1~\text{c}^2\text{m}^2$) in a context where students are already confused in a way that is likely to lead to more long term confusion.  Don't do this.  It is bad pedagogy / andragogy.

Comment: @XanderHenderson That’s a new word to me; thanks! Calling that red step (it was *the OP* who introduced it, btw) ‘curious-looking’ means I’m not *advocating* it, and [comment #13](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/26283/how-to-teach-that-10000x2-c2m2-is-wrong/26284?noredirect=1#comment69443_26284) contains my position statement on this matter (gosh); TLDR: *context matters*. And my previous comment is sincerely meant and stands.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to synthesize some of the discussion happening in the comments into an answer.

To me, a statement like
$$(100x\ \text{cm})^2 = 10\,000x^2\ \text{c}^2\text{m}^2$$
indicates that the student has not associated the symbol $\text{cm}$ with the unit $\text{centimeters}$ in the context of exponentiation. You can help them make this connection by rewriting the left-hand side as
$$(100x\ \text{centimeters})^2\!,$$
at which point they will hopefully see that $10\,000x^2\ \text{c}^2\text{m}^2$ is gobbledygook. In this form, it is also easier to see that
\begin{align*}
(100x\ \text{centimeters})^2 &= (x\ \text{meters})^2\!\\
&= x^2\ \text{square meters}\text{, so}\\
(100x\ \text{cm})^2 &= (x\ \text{m})^2\!\\
&= x^2\ \text{m}^2\!.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Although being a bit late to the question...

The underlying problem I see is that we first expose our students to a math symbology where single letters are used to name things, and that simply concatenating these characters means multiplication.

Then we introduce units where this no longer holds: $mm^2$ is not the same as $m^3$ or $mmm$, and we are surprised that students struggle with this situation. Decomposing $mm$ into $m \cdot m$ needs the student to understand that  $m$ as a prefix is not the same as $m$ as a unit (completely contradicting everything we taught before!), and that this "multiplication" is implicitly surrounded by a pair of parentheses. So, this will not aid in understanding the concept, but instead create more confusion.

In fact, unit prefixes need a special treatment.

- In most situations, units with prefixes should be viewed as a multi-letter entities (just like function names like $sin$, see [my answer here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/25163/how-can-you-elicit-the-log-x-log-cdot-x-error/25184#25184)), and not as a multiplication of a prefix with a unit.
- Only when it comes to unit conversions, then it might make sense to separate prefix and base unit, as in $mm = 0.001 \cdot m$ (but remind the students that they should use parentheses, so $mm = (0.001 \cdot m)$ would be the "safe" replacement).

So, it's more consistent to introduce units as multi-letter names, thus falling into a category that's needed anyway, e.g. for function names.

Comment: Arguably, this is part of why these kinds of mult-letter symbols are usually typeset with upright text, rather than italicized text.  This may be subtle, but $mm^2 = m^3$ (the variable $m$, multiplied by itself three times), while $\text{mm}^2 = (\text{millimeters})^2$ (i.e. square millimeters).

Comment: So, we want to teach our students to look not only at the letters, but also at their typesetting. And what about handwriting? IMHO, half of the problems that students have with mathematics, are not caused by mathematics itself, but by the notations that mathematicians use.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Using different typefaces to represent different kinds of objects is certainly not unique to mathematicians and in fact is more common among scientists, see [this NIST document](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/typefaces.pdf) which cites ISO 31. I agree that notation can cause many problems for students, but often it is because we are using the same symbol to mean different things. This convention allows us to distinguish the symbols $mm$ and $\text{mm}$.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I did not say that we should necessarily *rely* on the typesetting.  Rather, I indicated that this is part of *why* we typeset these things differently.  It is a subtle hint (beyond context alone, which should be clear enough) that these kinds of objects are different.  Also, this isn't really a problem with mathematics---it is a problem with physics and chemistry and engineering and other fields where units are a daily part of life.  Those dirty applied people are messing up our pure notation. :D

Comment: And, for the record, the only reason that I *commented* is that it really stood out to me that you had not properly typeset the sine function as $\sin$ (using `$\sin$`).  Because I was trained by my instructors and mentors, over a career in mathematics, to understand that $\sin$ should be upright.  I *really* stood out to me.  Which is another reason that it might be a good idea to teach students to write mathematics using a computer at an earlier age.